# For each word in a corpus, find how many senses it has according to WordNet

Tags: computational-linguistics, python, wordnet

I've come across this exercise in my studies and I do not know how to challenge, I've tried to follow examples though I can never find anything online that truly is symmetrical to what I'm trying to achieve.

`For each word occurring in the Reuters corpus, write code to find how many senses it has according to WordNet. Print a list of the 10 most frequently occurring words with 2 senses.`

If anyone could point me in the right direction of where to start!

I just hate even flipping the page if I haven't fully understood the entirety of it.

Comment: This question is too broad: we can't answer without knowing what it is that you don't understand. Your use of the words _challenge_ and _symmetrical_ doesn't make any sense to me (I can guess what you mean, but only from the context) so I wonder if you're having difficult understanding some of the basic words in the specification of the exercise.

Comment: Wordnet has interfaces in many programming languages. Find the library for your chosen programming language, and for each word, just find out how many meanings it has in Wordnet.

Answer (score 2):

Given your tags, I assume you're using the `nltk` library?

First you'll want the Reuters and Wordnet corpora:

```
from nltk.corpus import reuters, wordnet
```

Then, get your words from the Reuters corpus however you like: you probably don't want the entirety of `reuters.words()`, so you should narrow it down by field, file, dataset, etc.

Then, find how many senses each one has.

```
def count_senses(word):
    return len(wordnet.synsets(word))
```

For more information, look at [the NLTK documentation on Wordnet](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html).